# Magento2 sign-in link move to the search box Near

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, search, header, toplinks

How can i move account creation link and sign in link after the search box in header.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code into **default.xml** file of your theme

**file:** `your_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

Comment: I am using  luma theme  So plz give me code  and path aslo

Comment: i can try it but not any changes in front end , im using luma plz describe  path of default .xml